# Alternative to nested set?

Tags: tcl

I've got code which is of the form:

```
long_complicated_string_$i
```

for some indexing variable i and I'm writing statements like

```
my_proc long_complicated_string_$i long_complicated_string_$j
```

but all of the long_complicated_string_ parts make it hard to read so I write:

```
set x_$i long_complicated_string_$i
my_proc [set x_[set i]] [set x_[set j]]
```

This works and is an improvement but it's still not very nice. 
I'm very new to tcl and this seems a standard thing to want to do so I feel like there should be some easy way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you're doing that you're probably better off trying to use arrays instead, so variables go from `abc_$i` to `abc($i)`. The advantage comes when reading, as you can do this:

```
my_proc $x($i) $x($j)
```

instead of:

```
my_proc [set x_[set i]] [set x_[set j]]
```

or (because the innermost `set` isn't needed here anyway):

```
my_proc [set x_$i] [set x_$j]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd looked at arrays but I wasn't sure how I could set them correctly. The way I'm doing it now is `set x($i) long_string_$i; my_proc $x($i) $x($j)`